# React, Adding data from json to single post component

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I try to write website in React and that was going fine until now. I totally got stuck.

I have component with list of posts which is working fine. My problem is, that I dont know how to add data from JSON to single post component. I was trying to change geting my JSON data from list articles component to app.js and then passing it down to component with my list posts and to single post component, but then I have error with map() function.

```
//geting data from JSON and passing it through props down
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./style.css";

import SideBar from "../SideBar";
import MainContent from "../MainContent";
import blogData from "../../assets/data/blog.json";

const MainContainer = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const post = blogData.data;
    setPosts(post);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="main-container">
      <MainContent posts={posts} />
      <SideBar posts={posts} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default MainContainer;
```

```
//mapping through posts
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";
import Post from "../Post";

const MainContent = ({ posts }) => {
  return (
    <main className="main-content">
      {posts.map(post => {
        return <Post key={post.id} post={post} />;
      })}
    </main>
  );
};

export default MainContent;
```

```
//Post from list of posts
const Post = ({ post }) => {
  return (
    <div className="post">
      <Animated
        animationIn="bounceInLeft"
        animationOut="fadeOut"
        isVisible={true}
      >
        <h3 className="postTitle">{post.blogTitle}</h3>
        <div className="imgContainer">
          <img
            alt="travel"
            src={require("../../assets/img/" + post.blogImage)}
          ></img>
        </div>
        <p className="postDescription">{post.blogText}</p>
        <NavLink to={`/post/${post.id}`}>
          <h5 className="postLink">Read more</h5>
        </NavLink>
        <h5 className="posteDate">
          Posted on {post.postedOn} by {post.author}
        </h5>
      </Animated>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Post;
```

Here is link to my repo: 
https://github.com/Gitarrra92/travel-blog/

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I should have a state in my component with single object of specific id. I just still dont know how to do this. This is my SinglePost component

```
const SinglePost = ({ match }) => {
  const [singlePosts, setSinglePost] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const singlePost = blogSingleData.data;
    setSinglePost(singlePost);
    console.log(singlePost);
  }, [match]);

  return (
    <>
      <Socials />
    </>
  );
};

export default SinglePost;
```